# Android build target, duplicates, which to choose?

Tags: android

When creating a new android project, the build target has two choices:

Android 2.2, Android Open Source Project
AND
Google API's, Google Inc.

Both show Platform as 2.2 and API level 8

Which to choose (and why)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AVD` with Google API's contains google Api's like `GoogleMaps`.

For example:
If you application uses GoogleMaps, then you will have to use an AVD with Google API's.

Comment: @Macarse, then why would you ever NOT use google's APIs? What is the analogous benefit for choosing Android Open Source project?

Comment: @Vass: Some android devices don't have Google APIs. So depending on the carrier you might not have google's APIs.